# How to use generic methods in form?

Tags: c#, generics

I have to create form to create and edit same looking classes in my context. I created interface for this classes:

```
public interface ICatalogItem
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And have a view model for show them:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id{ set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now i create form and showed it using:

```
public void ShowForm<T>() where T : class, ICatalogItem
{
    FillGrid<T>(...);
}
```

And in FillGrid i have a simple code:

```
public void FillGrid<T>(....) where T : class, ICatalogItem
{
    ....
    var objs= myContext.Set<T>().Where(expressionFunc).OrderBy(arch => arch.Name);
    .....
}
```

But i have a problem what to do with buttons? For example for e search button i use code:

```
private void _btnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FillGrid<T>(...);
}
```

But of couse `<T>` can not be resolved here.
How to use generics in form?
Or only way - is create a base form and implement it for each class?

Comment: Do you _need_ `T` in `FillGrid<T>()`? Or can it be `CreateGrid<T>()` and `FillGrid()`?

Comment: I add a code snippet from `FillGrid<T>()`. Here is why i want to make it generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression, like this, to form a closure and give you access to `T`:

```
public void FillGrid<T>(....) where T : class, ICatalogItem
{
    ....
    var objs= myContext.Set<T>().Where(expressionFunc).OrderBy(arch => arch.Name);
    .....
    _btnSearch.Click += (s, e) => FillGrid<T>(...);
    ....
}
```

It's hard to tell from your code if this should be a recursive call or called from your other generic method, but this should help you wire it up.

Comment: I  dont understand how to this line `_btnSearch.Click += (s, e) => FillGrid<T>(...);` working. I mean how to send <T> to button handler?

Comment: @KliverMax - The `(s, e) => FillGrid<T>(...);` is the button handler done as a lambda expression. Since it is in the method containing the generic `T` it has full access to it. You would not use the `_btnSearchClick` method at all.